# How do I prevent ASP.NET Core detecting literal text I write as having special significance to the layout engine?

Tags: asp.net-core, view

I have the following in a view:

```
<p>
    @if (xyz == abc)
    {
        Start:
        ...
    }
</p>
```

The behaviour of Visual Studio seems to indicate that the "Start:" is interpreted as having special significance to the layout engine. It underlines it with a green wavy line and when I mouse over it, it displays a tooltip saying "This label has not been referenced".

The "Start:" is just text I want to be literally spat out onto the page. I don't want to invoke some special functionality. How do I make it understand this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an [explicit line transition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-2.1#explicit-line-transition-with-), which is simply the `@:` sequence. In your example, Razor is in a C# block when it meets `Start:`, so it assumes it's still working with C# code as `Start:` is valid C# syntax (it's a label for e.g. `goto`). Using `@:` explicitly instructs the Razor parser to treat the content as being HTML:

```html
<p>
    @if (xyz == abc)
    {
        @:Start:
        ...
    }
</p>
```

You can also use Razor's [`text`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-2.1#explicit-delimited-transition) element, which would give the same result:

```html
<p>
    @if (xyz == abc)
    {
        <text>Start:</text>
        ...
    }
</p>
```